# Editing package.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm having a hard time to understand how to run all of my .js files using package.js files
i have almost 2000.js scripts i need to run them one by one, i'm using a api made by gameflip
in the folder i found package.js, but i don't know how to use it ,
can anyone tell me how to do that ? thank you
here the script :

```
    {
  "name": "gfapi",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Gameflip API",
  "keywords": "Gameflip",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iJJi/gfapi",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/iJJi/gfapi/issues",
  "author": {
    "name": "Eng-Shien Wu",
    "email": "engshien.wu@ijji.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "repository": "iJJi/gfapi",                
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "bulk_listing": "node src/samples/bulk_listing.js",
    "test": "ENVIRONMENT=mocha mocha src/test --recursive",
    "docs": "jsdoc -c jsdoc_conf.js -d docs -P package.json index.js; docco -o docs/samples src/samples/*.js src/samples/*.rb"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "file-type": "^8.1.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.2",
    "node-rest-client-promise": "^3.1.1",
    "promise-ratelimit": "^0.0.3",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "marked": "^0.3.19",
    "docco": "^0.7.0",``
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. What you posted is the contents of package.json, a descriptor of your package, it's dependencies, and some other things. It has a `scripts` section though where you can put shortcuts for running scripts, you can execute those by `npm run <script name>`, for example `npm run builk-lisiting`

Answer (score 0):

What you posted isn't a `package.js` (I don't even know if it exists), but a `package.json`. It's generated by [NPM](https://npmjs.com/), the Node Package Manager. It's a list of all the project's dependencies. I think that what you're looking for are the npm scripts, they are in the `script` object of `package.json`.

```sh
npm run <script>

# For example :
npm run bulk_listing
npm run test
npm run docs
```

Each script will run its associated command in this `package.json`.

```sh
npm run bulk_listing
# Will do the same thing as:
node src/samples/bulk_listing.js
```

More about [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json).

---

#### The script I talked about below

If you want to run all the scripts, this should do the job :

```js
const fileNames = ["path/to/fileA", "fileB"]; // I assume you have something to get all the files path. Isn't that npm run bulk_listing ?

fileNames.forEach(async (path, index) => {
    // It's pretty much like 'node <path>'
    await require(path);
    // All the code here is executed AFTER the script has been launched
    console.log(`LAUNCHED ${index} | ${path}`)
});
```

Comment: that's the package.json file i got from the main directory that contain "samples" folder ect from the developed api i'm using !
actually , is there any other possible way to do that ?
i can run multiple files using concurrently !
if i do concurrently "node src\samples\files1js && node src\samples\files2js ect.."
it works but still it won't go far than 100 files
Is there maybe a way that i can have a script which i can put on all of node command files and then run the file itself to execute the commands in node ?

Comment: Here's what I would have done: I would have writen a .js script that gets all the names of the scripts you want to launch, and `require()` every single name in a loop. I don't really get why you want to do that though.

Comment: the reason is i have more tasks to do on my work, posting my items with api is just a part of it and i just have to do it like every 2-4 days , doing it takes a lot of my time, but i don't quite understand you, i'm sorry for asking this much questions i'm just too noobish at coding, hope i'm not doing anything wrong here by asking you this much questions x) so you said i have to write a js script with all the files names, i get that , but i don't get the "require() every single name in a loop"  damn bro feels  bad for asking idk why.. i apperciate helping me